# How do you transform a `FixedSqlAction` into a `StreamingDBIO` in Slick?

Tags: slick, akka-stream, slick-3.0, alpakka

I'm creating an akka-stream using Alpakka and the Slick module but I'm stuck in a type mismatch problem.

One branch is about getting the total number of invoices in their table:

```
  def getTotal(implicit session: SlickSession) = {
    import session.profile.api._
    val query = TableQuery[Tables.Invoice].length.result
    Slick.source(query)
  }
```

But the end line doesn't compile because Alpakka is expecting a `StreamingDBIO` but I'm providing a `FixedSqlAction[Int,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]`.

How can I move from the non-streaming result to the streaming one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the length of a table results in a single value, not a stream.  So the simplest way to get a `Source` to feed a stream is

```scala
def getTotal(implicit session: SlickSession): Source[Int, NotUsed] =
  Source.lazyFuture { () =>
    // Don't actually run the query until the stream has materialized and
    //  demand has reached the source
    val query = TableQuery[Tables.Invoice].length.result
    session.db.run(query)
  }
```

Alpakka's Slick connector is more oriented towards streaming (including managing pagination etc.) results of queries that have a lot of results.  For a single result, converting the `Future` of the result that vanilla Slick gives you into a stream is sufficient.

If you want to start executing the query as soon as you call `getTotal` (note that this whether or not the downstream ever runs or demands data from the source), you can have

```scala
def getTotal(implicit session: SlickSession): Source[Int, NotUsed] = {
  val query = TableQuery[Tables.Invoice].length.result
  Source.future(session.db.run(query))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would sth like this work for you?

```
def getTotal() = {
  // Doc Expressions (Scalar values)
  // https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/queries.html
  val query = TableQuery[Tables.Invoice].length.result

  val res = Await.result(session.db.run(query), 60.seconds)
  println(s"Result: $res")
  res
}
```